# SFML undefined reference

Tags: c++, sfml

I tried to link SFML with codeblocks, but I have some errors running the code from tutorial. This is code I tried to write after I saw that the one in tutorial doesn't work:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window w(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"da");
    return 0;
}
```

[This](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php) is the tutorial I followed.

After I compile the code above it gives me 4 error that say:

```
||=== Build: Release in SFML1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x97)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc4)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xaa)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6WindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd3)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6WindowD1Ev'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You're not linking against the libraries you need. So you did not set up your compiler/linker correctly, and are missing some linker flags.

Comment: Can you tell me what is missing or is too much?

Comment: No. I'm not sitting in front of your PC. You are. I don't know how you set up your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an error or have not followed the tutorial to the letter. This can happen. Everyone makes mistakes. Start over completely new and follow that tutorial to the letter. We cannot possibly know which mistake you made, because to do this, we would need to step through this tutorial as well and check if all the steps were followed correctly.

Please note that the latest version is 2.3 so you should follow the [2.3 tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-cb.php).